# TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on the CodedUI Test Automation project. i am developing a framework in which i am trying to access Test Cases in `VSTS` through `RestAPI`. I have worked on an MVC application previously in which i did the same thing to pull data from `VSTS` using `RestAPI`.
Now the problem is i am not able to access the `VSTS`. Everytime i am trying to access the `VSTS`, i got the exception `TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required`. 

I am using the same `PAT token`. I have all the required access on my team project. I am able to access all work items in my project from browser. I have tried all the option mentioned in below thread but still its not working.
[Client authentication error when starting Visual Studio 2015.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516736/client-authentication-error-when-starting-visual-studio-2015-3)
Any leads will be appreciated.
Below is my code to get data from `VSTS`:

```
public static List<WorkItem> GetWorkItemsWithSpecificFields(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var collectionUri = "https://<name>.visualstudio.com";
    var fields = new string[] {
        "System.Id",
        "System.Title",
        "System.WorkItemType",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork"
    };
    using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssBasicCredential("", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PATToken"])))
    {
        // Exception is coming on below line
        List<WorkItem> results = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(ids, fields).Result;
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working for me. How do you get that PAT? (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate)

Comment: Profile > Security > PAT. I had already generated the PAT token and used in an MVC applicaiton. There it is working like a charm. Same code i am trying in CodedUI but not working !!

Comment: Try to use connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>(); (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples#creating-a-vssconnection-instance-to-get-httpclients-for-rest-services)

Comment: @starain-MSFT Same exception. TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

Comment: Create a new PAT with all scope and try again.